# How to show the original image on photoswipe plugin

Tags: php, html, css

i downloaded one PhotoSwipe plugin http://photoswipe.com/ it is working fine,when i am showing the image in img tag i want show the original height and width ,  below code  i tried but image showing blur

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="">
<?php 
$i = 0;
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useralbum WHERE ssmid='$ssmid' ORDER BY photo_uploadedon DESC");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count >= 1){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$image = "original-photo/".$row['photo'];
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
?>
<figure <?php if(0 != $i) { ?>style="display:none;" <?php } ?>>
<a href="original-photo/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="<?php echo $width; ?>x<?php echo $height; ?>" data-med="original-photo/<?php echo $row['photo']?>" data-med-size="<?php echo $width; ?>x<?php echo $height; ?>" class="demo-gallery__img--main">
  <img src="img/user-album/thumbnail/<?php echo $row['thumbnail']?>" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" style='dispaly:none'/>
</a>
</figure>
</div>
```